# Imprimir OleObject ("word.application") com delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

Estou tentando imprimir um intervalo de páginas do `objeto` `OleObject` `("word.application")` no `delphi 6` e não estou conseguindo.

Usando o `printout(false) =` consigo imprimir com sucesso, mas quero imprimir um intervalo de páginas.

Agradeço muito pela ajuda.

**Código:**

```
if (OpenDialog1.Execute) then
  begin
    try
      // Cria objeto principal de controle do Word
      WinWord := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
      if (not (VarIsEmpty(WinWord))) then
      begin
        // Mostra o Word
        try
          WinWord.Visible := false;
          Docs := WinWord.Documents;
          // Abre um documento
          Doc := Docs.Open(OpenDialog1.FileName);

          //Doc.PrintOut(false);
          //Doc.PrintOut(Copies := 2);
          Doc.PrintOut(Background := false, Append := false, Range := wdPrintFromTo, OutputFileName := EmptyParam, From := 1, To := 2);
          // erro apresentado: "tipo não correspondente"
        finally
          // Fecha o Word
          //WinWord.close;
          //Doc.Close(SaveChanges := 0);
          WinWord.ActiveDocument.Close(SaveChanges := 0);
          WinWord.Quit;

          WinWord := Unassigned;
          Docs := Unassigned;
          Doc := Unassigned;

        end;
      end;
      //showmessage('Fim!');
    finally
    end;
  end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método `PrintOut` tem os seguintes parâmetros:

```
Var Background: OleVariant;
Var Append: OleVariant; 
Var Range: OleVariant;
Var OutputFileName: OleVariant; 
Var From: OleVariant; 
Var To_: OleVariant;
Var Item: OleVariant; 
Var Copies: OleVariant; 
Var Pages: OleVariant; 
Var PageType: OleVariant; 
Var PrintToFile: OleVariant; 
Var Collate: OleVariant;
Var ActivePrinterMacGX: OleVariant; 
Var ManualDuplexPrint: OleVariant; 
Var PrintZoomColumn: OleVariant; 
Var PrintZoomRow: OleVariant; 
Var PrintZoomPaperWidth: OleVariant; 
Var PrintZoomPaperHeight: OleVariant
```

a propriedade `Range` determina como vai funcionar a seleção de páginas de acordo com os seguintes valores:

- 0 - Imprime Todo o Documento
- 1 - imprime o texto selecionado
- 2 - Imprime a página atual
- 3 - Imprime o intervalo definido nos parâmetros [From] e [To]
- 4 - Imprime o intervalo do parâmetro [Pages]

Quando você não for utilizar um dos valores, passe como `EmptyParam`.

## Para imprimir um intervalo de páginas por exemplo:

```
var
  Range, Pages: Olevariant;
begin
  ...
  Range := 4;
  Pages := '1;3-5;7;11;9';
  Doc.PrintOut(EmptyParam {Background}, EmptyParam {Append}, Range, EmptyParam 
    {OutputFileName}, EmptyParam {From}, EmptyParam {To}, EmptyParam {Item}, EmptyParam 
    {Copies}, Pages);
```

## E se quiser utilizar um range de páginas **De X até Y**

```
var
  Range, From, To: Olevariant;
begin
  ...
  Range := 3;
  From := 3;
  To := 9;
  Doc.PrintOut(EmptyParam {Background}, EmptyParam {Append}, Range, EmptyParam 
    {OutputFileName}, From, To);
```

Comment: Deu certo. Muito obrigado!!